# Relocatable Code for a CMake/CUDA shared library

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I've stumbled upon a bit of a doozy compile error I've never encountered before. The exact code cannot be shared, so I will present an analogous situation. I have a shared library I'm developing, which compiles `__device__` tagged device code. These devices functions must be able to be used by `__global__` functions written by the user. Here is a boiled down set of code which recreates the raised error:

**The source code for the shared library: *device_function.cu***

```
__device__ int deviceFunction()
{
    return 1;
}
```

**The source code for the executable meant to call the device function: *soure.cu***

```
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ int deviceFunction();

__global__ void globalFunction()
{
    printf("%i", deviceFunction());
}

int main()
{
    globalFunction<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    return 0;
}
```

**The CMakeLists.txt file I've attempted to compile everything with:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

project(test)

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
enable_language(CUDA)

add_library(device_function SHARED device_function.cu)

add_executable(cu_test source.cu)
target_link_libraries(cu_test device_function)
```

Upon (attempted) compilation, I'm greeted with this:

```
[main] Building folder: relocatable-code 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /snap/cmake/current/bin/cmake --build /home/legayone/Documents/research-pathfinding-projects/cuda-programming/relocatable-code/build --config Debug --target all -j 18 --
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target device_function
[build] [ 50%] Built target device_function
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target cu_test
[build] [ 75%] Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/cu_test.dir/source.cu.o
[build] ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '_Z14deviceFunctionv'
[build] make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cu_test.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/cu_test.dir/source.cu.o] Error 255
[build] make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:111: CMakeFiles/cu_test.dir/all] Error 2
[build] make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

**What I've Tried**
I have scoured the web and arrived at solutions which all ultimately boil down to `CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON` or some form of `-rdc=true` or `-dc`. I have attempted adding separable compilation in the 3 possible combinations for `device_function` and `cu_test`, and I've done the same for `-rdc=true` and `-dc`, where I try it on one, then the other, then both. This is the format which I add `-rdc=true` and `-dc` to things in:

```
target_compile_options(cu_test PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-c "-lcudart -lcudadevrt -lcuda -rdc=true">)
```

~or~

```
target_compile_options(device_function PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-c "-lcudart -lcudadevrt -lcuda -rdc=true">)
```

**My question**
What am I missing or what am I doing wrong? I'd really like any executable to just be able to have the shared library `device_function` linked to it, and for it to be able to call the function inside that shared library. In the actual library this applies to, there are headers of course, but I have the includes sorted out :) its just linking.

**Where I suspect the issue is**
I suspect the issue is code relocatability. I'm aware special things have to be done to permit device functions from a different compilation unit to be used by an executable (or another library!), but what are those things and how do I do it in CMake?

Answer (score 1):

**A Kind Of Solution**

So it would seem that shared library based `__device__` functions being called by `__global__` functions from a separate compilation unit **is not possible**. I should note in this that there is a tremendous amount of conflicting information, specifically from this article:
https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/building-cuda-applications-cmake/, which seems to suggest it is possible, however its presented solutions do not work. Here is what works for me:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

project(test LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

include(CTest)

add_library(device_function STATIC device_function.cu)
add_library(shared_function SHARED shared_device_function.cu)
target_link_libraries(shared_function PUBLIC device_function)

add_executable(cu_test source.cu)
target_link_libraries(cu_test shared_function)
```

*What Works*

- linking works, as does compilation
- the device function in **device_function.cu** is able to be called from the global function in the executable source **source.cu**

*What Does Not Work*

- The actual file containing the device function must be a static library, but it can be linked to a shared library, allowing the user to use the whole library by just a single link to a whole shared library
- This static library method is, apparently, slower than the shared library method